# Can a single-qubit state be nontrivially extended to a non-pure state?

Tags: hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator, quantum-states

Consider a generic single-qubit state
$$\rho=\lambda_1\lvert \lambda_1\rangle\!\langle \lambda_1\rvert+\lambda_2\lvert \lambda_2\rangle\!\langle \lambda_2\rvert\in\mathcal H_S.$$
I am interested in understanding what are the possible extensions of $\rho$, that is, the states $\tilde\rho\in\mathcal H_{SE}$ such that 
$\operatorname{tr}_E(\tilde\rho)=\rho.$
If is relatively easy to find the general structure of extensions that are pure, but less so in the more general case of *non-pure* extensions.

In particular, is it possible to have a non-trivial extension of $\rho$ *which is **not** a purification*?

By non-trivial here I mean that it must also decrease the amount of uncertainty associated with $\rho$. This means no trivial extensions of the form $\tilde\rho=\rho\otimes\sigma$, and no extensions built by simply attaching a set of orthonormal states to the eigenvectors of $\rho$, that is, no extensions of the form $\tilde\rho=\sum_k \lambda_k \lvert\lambda_k\rangle\!\langle\lambda_k\rvert\otimes\sigma_k$ with $\lambda_k$ the eigenvalues of $\rho$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Just take any random purification with a large purifying space $\mathbb C^2\otimes C^d$, and trace the $\mathbb C^d$ component.

To give a randomly made up example,
$$
\rho = \left(\begin{matrix}
.25 & .20 & .10 & .05 \\
.20 & .25 & .00 & .05 \\
.10 & .00 & .25 & -.15 \\
.05 & .05 & -.15 & .25 
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
is a purification of the state
$$
\rho_A = \left(\begin{matrix}
.50 & .05 \\ .05 & .50
\end{matrix}\right)\ .
$$

That the example is not compatible with the special forms $\tilde\rho$ you give above can  be straightforwardly checked from the eigenvalues of $\rho$, which are incompatible with the forms $\tilde\rho$ you give above -- for  both those $\tilde\rho$, it holds that the eigenvalues of $\rho$ can be written as a sum of two  eigenvalues of $\tilde\rho$ each, which can be easily tested not to be the case.

To explain the last argument in more detail: 
Let $\tilde\rho=\sum \lambda_k |\lambda_k\rangle\langle\lambda_k|\otimes\sigma_k$ (which includes the first purification if all $\sigma_k$ are equal). Denote by $\mu_i(\sigma_k)$ the eigenvalues of $\sigma_k$. Then, the eigenvalues of $\tilde\rho$ are
$$
\tau_{i,k} = \lambda_k\,\mu_i(\sigma_k)\ .
$$
Thus, we have that
$$
\sum_i\tau_{i,k} = \lambda_k
$$
(as $\mathrm{tr}\,\sigma_k=1)$, i.e., each two (where "two" is the dimension of the purification) eigenvalues of $\tilde\rho$ add up to an eigenvalue $\lambda_k$ of $\rho$.

It can be easily checked that this property does not hold for the example.

---

Note that this richness of extensions is exactly a problem in computing the [squashed entanglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squashed_entanglement), where one optimizes over (non-pure) extensions of arbitrary dimensions.

Comment: ah, I think I see it now, thanks. Just a few notes. I guess you meant to write "*can be written as **product** of two eigenvalues* (which still does not seem quite accurate, but I get what you mean)? Also, do you know of some reference discussing the general structure of state extensions?

Comment: @glS Indeed, product. And I agree it is a bit ambigous, but with a bit of thought it should be clear?  (I can write a formula if you think it helps. I admit that I only came up with that argument while I was typing up the answer -- originally I just said: "It's random, so it will not have those properties.").  Not sure where to find sth. about this.  You can try papers on squashed entanglement (or Christandl's PhD thesis?).

Comment: yes yes it's not a problem. I would say that the spectrum of $\rho\otimes\sigma$ is given by the products of the eigenvalues of $\rho$ and $\sigma$, and for the other case we have a straightforward generalisation of this. I'll check that out, thanks

Comment: @glS Wait, no, I should have thought first (not enough coffee?).  I *do* indeed mean sum: If you trace the extension, you see that the eigenvalues are $\lambda_k\,\mathrm{tr}\sigma_k$, which are indeed the sum of two eigenvalues of the extension (namely $\lambda_k\,\mu_i(\sigma_k)$, with $\mu_i(\sigma_k)$ the eigenvalues of $\sigma_k$.

Comment: Have edited the answer.

Comment: ah, yes of course. I was thinking of the eigenvalues of the purification, which are indeed products of the eigenvalues of the components, while you were referring to how these eigenvalues relate to the original state. All clear now.